# Oracle SQL UPDATE query with data and field matching from another table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I have two tables in an Oracle SQL-database. The fields which are of interest are these:

Table A:
Reference-A | Type-A | Timestamp-A

Table B:
Reference-B | Type-B | Timestamp-B

The timestamp field in Table B is newly created and therefore all NULL, and I'd like to update that field with timestamp values from table A.

Reference-A and reference-B do match one-to-one, but there are multiple rows for each reference with different Type, so I also need to select on the type. Type-A and Type-B aren't the same, so I need to do an IF-ELSE-matching on them, eg: Type-B1 -> Type-A1, Type-B2 -> Type-A2

Not all combinations of Reference-B and Type-B have a match in table A, so for those cases it can just set the timestamp in Table-B to null.

So how does the SQL query for this UPDATE statement look like? I've tried this one (pseudo);

```
UPDATE B
SET timestamp = (
    SELECT A.timestamp 
    FROM A, B
    WHERE A.reference = B.reference
      AND A.type = 
        (CASE 
          WHEN B.type = 'B1' 
            THEN 'A1'
          WHEN B.type = 'B2' 
            THEN 'A2' 
          WHEN B.type = 'B3' 
            THEN 'A3'
          WHEN B.type = 'B4' 
            THEN 'A4' 
        END)
);
```

But when I run this query, I get the following error: "SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row".

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using DISTINCT in the SELECT query.

Comment: What that error means is that your subquery is returning more than one row for at least one set of a.reference and a.type. You need to decide what the subquery should return if it matches to more than one timestamp - should it return the latest or earliest timestamp (max/min)? A random timestamp (`rownum = 1`)? Only you know your data and your requirements, so only you can decide...

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE B
SET timestamp = (
    SELECT A.timestamp 
    FROM A
    WHERE A.reference = B.reference
      AND A.type = 
        (CASE 
          WHEN B.type = 'B1' 
            THEN 'A1'
          WHEN B.type = 'B2' 
            THEN 'A2' 
          WHEN B.type = 'B3' 
            THEN 'A3'
          WHEN B.type = 'B4' 
            THEN 'A4' 
        END)
      AND rownum < 2 -- !!! select only 1 row
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in error message, your sub query is returning more than one row. In the sub query, you don't need to join table B again. If table Reference-A and Reference-B do match one-to-one, you could update your query like this

```
UPDATE B
SET timestamp = (
    SELECT A.timestamp 
    FROM A
    WHERE A.reference = B.reference
      AND A.type = 
        (CASE 
          WHEN B.type = 'B1' 
            THEN 'A1'
          WHEN B.type = 'B2' 
            THEN 'A2' 
          WHEN B.type = 'B3' 
            THEN 'A3'
          WHEN B.type = 'B4' 
            THEN 'A4' 
        END)
);
```